# Merge dictionary without duplicating key and make empty string in case different key

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, merge

suppose I have a list

```
A = [{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':4,'b':5},{'a':6,'c':7}]
```

and I want to make a function which
get two input dictionary and merge input

for example
merge `A[0], A[1], and A[2]`
output is

```
{'a':[1,4,6],'b':[2,5,''],'c':[3,'',7]}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
A = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5}, {'a': 6, 'c': 7}]

res = {k: [] for d in A for k in d}
for d in A:
    for k in res:
        res[k].append(d.get(k, ""))

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': [1, 4, 6], 'b': [2, 5, ''], 'c': [3, '', 7]}
```